# Angular 6 Mat Table DataSource w/ Observables

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I have an Angular 6 with Mat Tables retrieving related data from two different services. The first service retrieves all data it's data and then passes 
 criteria to the second through mergeMap to retrieve the addition data for each record returned in the first.

My issue is that I can see the data being returned w/o error and the table iterating rows in the output **but** nothing being displayed in the table. The two relevant classes are:

```
export class GetMyShizz implements OnInit{
     dataSource = new IssueDataSource(this.issueService);
     displayedColumns: string[] = ['created', 'updated', 'number', 'title', 'pipeline', 'estimate'];
     constructor(private issueService: IssueService) {}
     ngOnInit() {}
}
export class IssueDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
      constructor(private issueService: IssueService) {
        super();
      }
      connect(): Observable<any> {
        return this.issueService.getIssues()
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((ghIssues) => {
                const zhIssuesQueries: Observable<any>[] = [];
                for (let ghIssue of ghIssues) {
                    zhIssuesQueries.push(this.issueService.getZHIssue(ghIssue.number));
                }
                return forkJoin(...zhIssuesQueries);
            })
        )
      }
      disconnect() {
      }
}
```

I'm fairly certain it has to do with the way i am assigning the DataSource (issueDataSource) for the table in the first class but not sure how to make the reference. It worked when I was only calling one service (before I added the mergeMap stoof.)

#### Edit (w/ HTML template)

```
  <div class="issue-table-container">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="issue-table"
           matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Issue #</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.number}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><b>{{row.title}}</b>
        <button mat-raised-button class="label-button" *ngFor="let label of row.labels" [ngStyle]="setBadgeStyles(label.color)">{{label.name}}</button></td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
          Created
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_at | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="updated">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
          Updated
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.updated_at | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="estimate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
          Estimate
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.estimate}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="pipeline">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
          Pipeline
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.pipeline}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: If the table is iterating the correct number of rows/columns then my guess it is on the html side. Mind adding the html portion for your table?

Comment: Updated with HTML. If I could figure out how to dump the result of the forkJoin, that would be helpful.And yes the number of rows is correct.